# Ubuntu 16.04 - Logs in then immediately logs me out

Tags: login

Ubuntu 16.04
Nvidia gtx 960 - Using nvidias drivers
4.4.21 kernel
I tried deleting .Xauthority file, and restarted lightdm, it does not regenerate the file, so now I have no .Xauthority file.

Very frustrating because I dong know where to look for errors. what can I check?

What happened was I was losing some stuff into memory and I ran out of memory. So I cycled the machine. Once this happened I could not get past the login screen.

Comment: Did you reboot after deleting the .Xauthority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your kernel with a recent update? Then you have to recompile the nvidia driver since it won't work with the new kernel out of the box.

Just reinstall your nvidia driver and that should fix the issue.

Comment: You saved my skin! I could not believe I had to do this... thanks again.